# Custom element from plugin in structure-like hierarchy

Tags: plugin-development, craft3

I'm working on a plugin that would require a custom element to have a hierarchy, as in, possibly have a parent set or not. Much like entries have when used in a structure.

I've got my element set up and all the custom fields and the title get saved just fine, however I've hit a wall trying to get them have a parent.

I've tried setting the parent property to another element and after I hit save, it does not seem to properly register it.

Is there a specific way to go about this? The documentation is rather sparse on implementing a hierarchical custom element.

Any pointers or examples on how to implement this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Maybe check the source code of Categories?

Comment: Would love to know if there's more info on this now!